# How to read/edit/save information from multiple forms in the same page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I'm working with JavaScript, HTML and PHP on this website where I have a GUI quite similar with an IDE. What I'm trying to say is that I have multiple tabs with diferrent buttons that generate multiple forms on a big .

When I'm done with filling all the fields from these multiple forms, it will lately all be exported into a JSON object. But that's not the problem for now.

The big issue here is all about keeping the information and allowing the user to later edit it before exporting everything to JSON.

Any sugestions?

Regards

Comment: Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: Checkout my answer with HTML5 localstorage will help you.

Comment: I have edited the Answer for some more information about json.parse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its JSON Object. you can change like below.

```
var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}',
    obj = JSON.parse(json);

alert(obj.count);
```

Refer for more information
[Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

To Store the JSON into `HTML5` Localstorage Concept will help you.

1. [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)
2. [Push JSON Objects to array in localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083919/push-json-objects-to-array-in-localstorage)

### I Prefer BackBoneJS

Check the below SO Answer

[Backbone.js Multi-Step Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553333/backbone-js-multi-step-form)

Comment: this way really slows down the performance, fyi.  over 60 items, you are suffering big time.

Comment: Ended using Backbone.js. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need two way data binding, jquery is good or angular has great options for this kinda stuff.